# How does Firebase config get the region/country for a device?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a problem and I need to know how does the firebase config gets the region/country for a user, is the region based on google account, or what ? also how does it get the region without any permission ?

Comment: I found that firebase gets the region/country through the **Internet-Provider**.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the problem when I try to get the device region. Here are many ways to get this region, you can use below ways:

1. use "ro.carrier" get the cid;
2. use Locale.getDefault().getCountry() get the short country name;
3. use (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) to get the region of SIM card.

you may use all of them and given priority.

For Firebase, I have met a short code below, maybe this can help you:

```
 String feature_url = "feature_config";
    Log.d(TAG, "init, feature_url: " + feature_url);
    mRootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRootReference.child(feature_url).child(BuildConfiguration.DEBUG ? "debug" : "release")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange");
                    FeatureConfig.getInstance().updateConfig(dataSnapshot);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled");
                }
            });
```

this ie a method used to get the DataSnapShot and then get the region information from it.

Since I don`t know whether this could help you, I don`t past to much code here.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

***This may give you some idea!!!***

You have your own FCM key is strictly required for native implementation.

**While setup to get FCM key user should provide region/country**

*How to set up your own FCM keys:*

1) Log in with your Google Account

Open https://console.firebase.google.com/ and log in using your Google account (if the page asks you to do so).

2) Click on Create New Project

In the next box that appears, click on Create **New project**.

3) Compose the Project Name and select your country/region

You’ll now be prompted with a modal box like the one shown below. Under Project name, write the name you want and below that, select your Country/region. Once you’ve done this, click on the Create Project.

[image]

For detail go through [this](https://support.pushcrew.com/support/solutions/articles/9000064351-setting-up-your-fcm-keys-previously-called-gcm-)